# Language specific words dataset

Tags: data-request, dictionary

Where can I find a dataset with all (or the most important) words from a language? For example, I need a dictionary for the Romanian language.

In the first stage just the words, the frequency would be useful also, nothing else.

Comment: What do you need? Just words or wordforms; meanings; translations; sematical relations? Can you be a little more clear?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you just need a list of {word, frequency} couples, for each language, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you're looking for a [lexicon](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+lexicon&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8), which normally contain words with their inflections, derivatives, frequencies, etc, derived from a corpus of text in a particular language.

The only thing that I could find for Romanian is the [Romanian WordForm Lexicon](http://ws.racai.ro:9191/repository/browse/romanian-wordform-lexicon/829373c4fb6811e2a8ad00237df3e358b11527e59e61482c9326eef392509cd4/), which contains lexical data extracted from the [Romanian Balanced Corpus](http://ws.racai.ro:9191/repository/browse/romanian-balanced-corpus/8997021cfb6811e2a8ad00237df3e35848d354472f7b4f76985dcfbbaa26d04d/), and it has slightly restricted use. It seems that you need to contact Dan Tufis, who is the maintainer. Information about the lexicon can be found [here](http://ws.racai.ro:9191/narratives/batch1/RoTblWordForm.pdf), including contact information for Dan Tufis, the structure of the lexicon, how to cite the lexicon, etc.

You may also be interested in the [Romanian WordNet](http://ws.racai.ro:9191/repository/browse/romanian-wordnet-30/4611a43efb6811e2a8ad00237df3e3580b6b50d1111c4a6292694bded91d5c14/), which contains sets of cognitive synonyms; it is a derivative work of [Princeton's original WordNet project for English](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/), and falls under the same jurisdiction as the Romanian WordForm Lexicon.

Unfortunately I don't know what is required to use MetaShare (which hosts/licenses all of these documents); it is part of [MetaNet](http://www.meta-net.eu/), the European Multilingual Technology Alliance.

Comment: MetaShare is an archiving infrastructure and hosts materials with a wide range of licences, many of which aren't open, some are open.

Comment: @jknappen Thanks for your comment. It would seem that the two items I sourced on MetaShare are MS Commons, available for academic use with permission of the license holder, and non-redistributable. So, the OP would need to fill out the required forms in order to obtain a copy. Not the *best* solution, but a solution nonetheless!

Answer (score 1):

Specifically looking for Romanian, there is babelnet 2.5.1 (a multilingual wordnet) available under an Open licence from http://babelnet.org/. (Open Multilingual Wordnet has no Romanian section yet.)

A free corpus containg a good wealth of Romanian is europarl available from many places.

For a dictionary, consider wiktionary (both ro.wiktionary.org and the Romanian entries from en.wiktionary.org).

Anything else I am aware of may be free of charge for academic research, but not Open Data (e.g. the Leipzig Wortschatz corpora, http://corpora.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/)